# If a function A $\to$ B is bijective then if A is infinite, so it is B (Proof with Dedekind's definition of infinite sets).

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Theorem: Be A, B sets that can be be mapped bijectively. If A is infinite, so it is B. Note that we only use Dedekind's definition of infinite sets here: If N $ \subset$ M and f: M $\to$ N bijective then M is infinite.**

There is a proof in my textbook I do not understand. The proof looks like this:

*Let A' $ \subset$ A and $f$: A $\to$ A' bijective. Further we assume $h$: A $\to$ B bijective.
We assume $g: h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$: B $\to$ B.
Then $g$ is injective. There's some x $\in$ A - A', so $h(x) \notin rng(g)$. More precisely it holds: rng($g$) = $h''A' \subset h''A = B$.
Therefore $g: B \to rng(g) \subset B$ is a witness for the infinity of B.*

I am too new to set theory to understand this proof. Following you see my so-far attempt to make some sense of the upper proof:

1. Let A' $ \subset$ A and $f$: A $\to$ A' bijective. Further we assume $h$: A $\to$ B bijective. (Just the premises of the theorem.)
2. Further we assume a function $g: h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$, so the mapping goes: B $\to$ A $\to$ A' $\to$ A $\to$ B. Because of A' $ \subset$ A we know that some x $\in$ A - A'. In the case of $h$: A $\to$ B alone, which is bijective, it means that x has an image $h(x)$ which is in rng($h$) = B, so $h(x)$ $\in$ B. But in case of $g$ the element $h(x)$ $\notin$ rng($g$) because x cannot map from A' going forward, so it cannot be in rng($g$) as $h(x)$. Therefore rng($g$) $\subset$ B.
3. But then why $g: B \to rng(g)$ is bijective?

So basically I need someone to lead me thru the upper proof of my textbook by explaining more what's going on than the short proof tells. I just added my thoughts, so that you can see my thinking/mistakes and also see that I tried.

Comment: Use mathjax to write mathematical expressions, here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I tried my best but couldn't find how to make an inverse function f^-1 to look properly. Sorry. Is this right? $f^-1$ Because then I will change it.

Comment: Use curly brackets if you want to group things. So `$f^{-1}$` will tell mathjax to group "-1" into a single unit, and then the `^` symbols tells it to superscript it. So you get $f^{-1}$.

Comment: For future reference: write entire mathematical expressions, not just individual symbols, in math mode. In other words, write `$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$` (which yields "$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$") instead of `f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10` which yields a much uglier "f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $g$, as constructed, is just the identity function. That is, for every $b\in B$, you have $g(b)=b$. Therefore, the conclusion that $\mathrm{rng}(g)\subset B$ is wrong.

More precisely, your problem arrives when you say this:

> Because of A' ⊂ A there is some x ∈ A - A' which is not mapped thru f^-1 (i.e. from A' → A), so that f^-1(x) ∉ rng(f^-1)

The thing is that sure, there exists some $x$ such that $x\in A\setminus A'$. However, that *x* is **not** in the **domain** of $f^{-1}$, so it makes no sense to speak of the element $f^{-1}(x)$.

---

What I instead advise you do is to define the set $B'=h(A')$ and try

1. Prove that $B'\neq B$ (i.e., prove that $B'\subset B$)
2. Find a bijection between $B'$ and $B$ (do this using the known bijection $f$ between $A'$ and $A$).

---

*After the edit*:

As far as I see, your only problem is with proving that $g:B\to\mathrm{rng}(g)$ is a bijective function. But this is a fairly simple thing to prove. In fact, the function is surjective practically by **definition** (i.e., every element in its codomain must, by definition, be in the range), and it is injective because it is a composite of injective functions, and those are always injective.

If you want, a direct proof that $g$ is injective would be this. If $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, then $$g(x_1)=h(f(h^{-1}(x_1)))=h(f(h^{-1}(x_2)))=g(x_2).$$

Now, everything falls out because of injectivity:

1. Because $h$ is injective, we know that $h(a)=h(b)\implies a=b$, so we have (substitute $a=f(h^{-1}(x_1))$, $b=f(h^{-1}(x_2))$) that $f(h^{-1}(x_1))=f(h^{-1}(x_2))$.
2. Now, because $f$ is injective, we know that $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$, so we have (substitute $a=h^{-1}(x_1), b=h^{-1}(x_2)$) that $h^{-1}(x_1)=h^{-1}(x_2)$.
3. Because $h^{-1}$ is injective, we know that $h^{-1}(a)=h^{-1}(b)\implies a=b$, so we have (substitute $a=x_1, b=x_2$) that $x_1=x_2$.

Therefore, we proved that $g(x_1)=g(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$, so we proved that $g$ is injective.

**minor point:**

Let me just take a minute to also comment on your proof. It is a little confusingly written, and it makes things look more complicated than they really are. Especially here:

> But in case of $g$ the element $h(x)$ $\notin$ rng($g$) because x cannot map from A' going forward, so it cannot be in rng($g$) as $h(x)$. Therefore $\mathrm{rng}(g) \subset B$.

This looks really strange, and I think can be written much more clearly. In particular, you want to prove that $\mathrm{rng}(g)\neq B$, You can prove that by finding a $y$ that is in $B$, but not in $\mathrm{rng}(g)$.

*proof*: So, we take $x\in A\setminus A'$ (we know such a value exists) and define $y=h(x)$.. I claim that $y\in B$ and $y\notin \mathrm{rng}(g)$.The first part is obvious, so let me just prove the second. The proof will be by contradiction. Assume $y\in \mathrm{rng}(g)$. This means (by the definition of $\mathrm{rng}$ that there exists some $x'\in B$ such that $$g(x')=y.$$

Further, we know $y=h(x)$ and we know that $g=h\circ f\circ h^{-1}$. So we can write out the above equation as

$$h(f(h^{-1}(x'))) = h(x)$$

from the injectivity of $h$, we can now conclude that $x=f(h^{-1}(x'))$. This means, by definition, that $x\in\mathrm{rng}(f)$. But we know that $\mathrm{rng}(f)=A'$, so we conclude that $x\in A'$.

But we started out the proof by taking $x\in A\setminus A'$, which is in contradiction with the conclusion. So the premise of our proof by contradiction, which was "$y\in \mathrm{rng}(g)$", must be wrong. So $g\notin\mathrm{rng}(g)$, which is what we wanted to show. End of proof.

Comment: This is the proof from a german set-theory book: Let A' $\subset$ A and f: A $\to$ A'. Also let be h: A $\to$ B bijective. We assume g = h $\circ$ f $\circ$ h^-1: B $\to$ B. g is injective. There is x $\in$ A - A', so h(x) $\notin$ rng(g), more precisely: rng(g) = h''A' $\subset$ h''A = B. Therefore g: B $\to$ rng(g) $\subset$ B a witness of the infinity of B. I just do not understand this short proof I'd need more explanation of things in between. Can u use this sketch to give a more explanative proof?

Comment: @Pippen First of all, like I already said, please use mathjax to write mathematical expressions. Second of all, I suggest you *add* the proof into your question and explain, specifically, which part is confusing you. Or, alternatively, follow the  advice I gave in the final part of my answer. Did you try to do points 1 and 2 I wrote? Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I will rewrite my question with the proof I read and mark the spot I don't understand. That's probably best. I'll do it tomorrow or the day after, I have to work unfortunately.

Comment: @Pippen Write a comment here so I will get the message to re-check the question. Also, I suggest you (rather than trying to understand the proof someone else wrote) follow my advice and try to prove the statement yourself (use the guideline I laid out already). It might take 10% more work, but it will have 10x the staying power in your head. I know you don't want to, and I know it will be confusing, but trust me, I am speaking from experience.

Comment: Hi, I tried a new shot, though I do not understand even the meaning of some strings in the proof, so I rewrote the whole question and added my thoughts. It should be straight forward now. Just look at it and maybe you can help. I wanna understand the proof from the textbook because it's what I am working with.

Comment: @Pippen See my expanded answer.

Comment: Just for my understanding: why is $y = h(x) \in B$? Because of the lone function $h: A \to B$, right? But in $g$ it is $y = h(x) \notin B$, as well as $y = h(x) \notin rng(g)$, right? So if we just look at $g$ then $y$ is neither in B nor rng(g) which we didn't want to. Or can we just throw $h$ in the mix as well?

Comment: Also can I just reason: $g: B \to rng(g)$ is bijective because $g$ is just a composition of only bijective functions that are shuffled around a little bit, so g must be bijective with rng(g).

Comment: @Pippen $h(x)$ is an element of $B$ because the codomain of $h$ is $B$, correct. I have no idea what you mean by the sentence "But in $g$ it is $y=h(x)\notin B$".  The point is that $y$ is in $B$, and it is not in $\mathrm{rng}(g)$. The element is either in the set or not, it cannot be "in" the set only "if we just look at $g$". That makes zero sense. Your comments, overall, are very confusing to me. Please limit them to one question at a time. And make it specific. Which part of the proof is confusing to you?

Comment: @Pippen This is part of a larger point you will need to learn to conquer this and more advanced math topics. The point is this: you need to ***slow down***. Your mind is racing allover the place and you are making statements that are nonsensical because they are not mathematically rigorous. Mathematics is a world comprised of **small steps**. Each proof has several small steps, and you need to look a each step on its own and it must make sense.

Comment: @Pippen Yes, you can reason that $g$ is bijective because it is a composition of bijective functions. But you can only do that **if you already know** that compositions of bijective functions are bijectieve.

Comment: Another question about the function g. What describes correctly how $g$ maps: 1) $g: B \to A \to A' \to B$ or 2) $g: B \to A \to A' \to A \to B$ or 3) neither? Remark: As I understand all the letters refer to a domain or codomain/range, so e.g. $e: A \to B \to C$ I'd understand as: A is the domain for the codomain B which is the domain for the codomain C.

Comment: @Pippen since $g=h\circ h\circ h^-1$, you have $h^{-1}$ which maps $B\to A$, you have $f$ which maps $A \to A$ (but the **range** of $f$ is $A'$) and you have $h$ which maps $A\to B$. So $g: B\to A\to A\to B$ would "describe" how $g$ maps.

Comment: That's what I do not understand about $g: h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$. If we go precisely from $h^{-1}$ to $f$ to $h$ it should look $g: B \to A \to A \to A' \to A \to B$, wouldn't u agree? But then the whole proof collapses. Why can u leave out some domains/codomains and arrive at $g: B \to A \to A' \to B$?

Comment: @Pippen No I would not agree. When you are making a composition of functions, you must always have a domain of one function that is the codomain of the previous one. I.e., if $f_1: A\to B$, and $f_2:B\to C$, then $f_2\circ f_1: A\to B\to C$.

Comment: Ok, I checked it and now I got it. Thank you very much for your teaching effort and your patience.

Comment: @Pippen Happy to help, and good luck with your studies :)